# Connect to postgres on docker container via localhost is failed

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker, psql, docker-desktop

I'm constructing a postgres server on docker container by `docker run` command as follows (environmental parameters are set properly).

```
  docker run \
      --name zero2prod \
      -e POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER} \
      -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD} \
      -e POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME} \
      -p "${DB_PORT}":5432 \
      -d postgres \
      postgres -N 1000
```

But, `psql` command failed to connect the server. I typed the command as follows.

```
PGPASSWORD="${DB_PASSWORD}" psql -h "localhost" -U "${DB_USER}" -p "${DB_PORT}" -d "postgres"
```

The error message is this.

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Does anyone knows why the command failed?

Note: I'm using windows 10 machine and `docker` environment was installed using `Docker Desktop for Windows`.

Comment: Can you verify from the container logs that the database is running correctly?

Comment: Yes, container said "database system is ready to accept connections" at the end of log, and I can connect the database using psql command from inner shell of the container.

Comment: I found psql command failed when host port and container port indicated by -p option is same. But I don't know why...

Comment: @T.A if you found the solution already please don't add it to your question but write it as an answer to the post. It makes it easier for others to find as well

Comment: @st.huber Thank you for your comment. I moved my answer to Answer section.

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution.

`psql` command executed successfully. I changed `p` option of `docker run` changed as follows.

- Before : `-p 5432:5432`
- After  : `-p 5555:5432`

I don't know why `psql` command failed when the host port is same with container port `5432`.